# Static ground noise when WiFi card is turned on

Tags: wireless, sound, noise

I have an annoying static noise problem when I turn on the Wifi. If I turn off the Wifi the noise disappears.

This problem is occurring in Ubuntu on a laptop on which I have installed both Ubuntu 20.04 and Windows, but on Windows the problem does not occur.

I have tried all the static noise solutions I have come across, but nothing has resolved it.

Hardware:

- Acer Spin 5 laptot
- -network
  description: Wireless interface
  product: QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter
  vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
  physical id: 0
  bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
  logical name: wlp1s0
  version: 32

  ```
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ath10k_pci driverversion=5.13.0-28-generic firmware=WLAN.RM.4.4.1-00140-QCARMSWPZ-1  latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
   resources: irq:129 memory:b1000000-b11fffff
  ```

Think i tried:

- all the links to ground noise and speaker noise i found on stack.

Comment: It may not have a solution. The reason is badly designed (i.e. made to a very cheap price point) hardware and on top some modified proprietary sound driver/software (Windows only) that masks the problem.

Comment: Hello and Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.  I'm not an expert in this area of things; I just came across your question when reviewing posts in the "First Questions" queue.  I made some slight edits, but overall the main suggestions I would have for you would be to (a) list the hardware involved, (b) list at least some of the links to things you have tried so that people don't waste time suggesting things you have already tried.  I wonder if there might be a way to decrease the power to the WiFi card.  Perhaps the Windows driver uses a different setting by default.